Problem configuring Hibernate and HikariCP
I'm trying my Hibernate installation with HikariCP. This is a very recommended connection pool, so I'm testing my software with it.
The environment development is:

JDK21
Hikari 5.1.0
Hibernate 5.3.29.Final
hibernate-hikari component 5.3.29.Final
MySQL 8.0.32
Eclipse STS 4.4.25

My Hibernate configuration with Hikari is:
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">xxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource</property>
    
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
    
    
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">30000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime">2000000</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">30000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold">500</property>
    

    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>

I set leakDetectionThreshold to 500 to try to find any slow query. I also set log level to TRACE in com.* package.
The performance is much worse than before.
I found these two issues.

A simple (end - start) measure log this:

SAVE RESULTS 166 ms
SAVE RESULTS 116 ms
SAVE RESULTS 168 ms
SAVE RESULTS 192 ms
SAVE RESULTS 51009 ms
SAVE RESULTS 50883 ms
SAVE RESULTS 50978 ms
It seems there is a moment in which the database works much slower.

Hikari raises this exception


Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 178298ms (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=5)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:686) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:144) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:99) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:?]
at org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider.getConnection(HikariCPConnectionProvider.java:77) ~[hibernate-hikaricp-5.3.29.Final.jar:5.3.29.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.29.Final.jar:5.3.29.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.29.Final.jar:5.3.29.Final]
... 43 more

I don't know if config parameters are deeply wrong, but it's my first approach to Hibernate + Hikari.
Any help is very appreciated. Thanks
